# In what authorative specification is the onChange event exhaustively defined?

Tags: html, events, dom, standards, onchange

I was slightly surprised to find out that the onChange event in an html document is fired on a text input or textarea not at the very moment when its value actually changes, but only when focus leaves the element (if its value has changed, of course).

So I was looking for the specification that states that, and I can't find it. I can find millions of tutorials explaining that, including W3Schools' ones, but I can't find the standard that defines when the event is expected to be fired.

In the HTML5 specification itself, the event's name is listed but nothing is said about it:
http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/

In this other spec, "DOM level 3 Events Specification", it is not even mentioned:
http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/

So what is the standard that defines it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change

Comment: awesome question! I was shocked as I gradually learned that there's no clear, authoritative specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's briefly mentioned in the ***Intrinsic events section*** of the [**W3C 4.01 specification**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3):

> "The `onchange` event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its
>   value has been modified since gaining focus".

It's also mentioned a little more extensively on [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441307.aspx):

> "This event is fired when the contents are committed and not while the
>   value is changing. For example, on a text box, this event is not fired
>   while the user is typing, but rather when the user commits the change
>   by leaving the text box that has focus. 
>   In addition, this event is executed before the code specified by `onblur` when the control is also
>   losing the focus."

Finally, on the [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change):

> Depending on the kind of the form element being changed and the way
>   the user interacts with the element, the change event fires at a
>   different moment:
>
> - When the element is activated (by clicking or using the keyboard) for `<input type="radio">` and `<input type="checkbox">;`
> - When the user commits the change explicitly (e.g. by selecting a value from a `<select>`'s dropdown with a mouse click, by selecting a date from a date pickier for `<input type="date">`, by selecting a file 
>     in the file picker for `<input type="file">`, etc.);
> - When the element loses focus after its value was changed, but not committed (e.g. after editing the value of `<textarea>` or `<input type="text">`).

Another potentially useful link - **[WhatWg - specification - change event.](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#event-input-change)**

Comment: Thanks. The WhatWg one seems to be the closest thing to a standard that exists right now. (It's insanely convolute, though). I almost missed it :) (I was going to comment I found it linked from in the MDN one). Interesting that W3C decided to completely drop a piece of specification in HTML5 which was pretty clear in HTML4, though incomplete and partly untrue (or no more true: what stated there doesn't apply to checkboxes and radios) instead of completing and improving it.